# How to find a dynamic selector that changes after each page render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to click a button on a website that I don't own. The selector for the button is #pop_1609947672477 > div > div > div.inner-content > div > div > div > button. However, the number after the #pop changes after each page refresh, making it impossible to reliably select the button.

Is there a way to select the button regardless of the dynamic number? Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a common anti crawler technique. I'm presuming you're trying to crawl someone that doesn't want to be crawled. Either way this answer can't be answered based on the very limited amount of information you've added here

Comment: Is `#pop_1609947672477` the only element that starts with an id of `#pop_` within the page?

Comment: yes, I copy the selector from the div himself

Answer (score 0):

If the element you are interested in is the only element having an id that starts with `#pop_` within the page, you can select it as follows:

```
[id^=pop_] > div > div > div.inner-content > div > div > div > button
```

If there are multiple elements having an id that starts with `#pop_`, then you will need to find out a pattern that can differentiate them.

For example, if the element you want to find always appears as the first element, you can add some additional constraints to the selector, or filter the result after the selection.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=pop_] > div > div > div.inner-content > div > div > div > button');

// highlight the selected elements
elements.forEach(el => el.style.background = 'tomato');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pop_1234">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="inner-content">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <button>The Element</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="not_pop_1234">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="inner-content">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <button>Not The Element</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to find and click the button, see this script. I have removed ALL the inner divs as it muddies the water a bit.

The bit of magic is this bit, basically `'div[id^="pop_"] button'` asking the page to return all elements that starts with `id=pop_`  (the `^` does this)

So take a look and run this script. This will open chrome, hit F12 and navigate to the console tab, after 3 secs you will see a console.log message so we know the button has been clicked.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="pop_1111">
      <button onclick="report(1111);">The first element</button>
    </div>
    <div id="pop_2222">
      <button onclick="report(2222);">The second element</button>
    </div>
    <div id="pop_9876">
      <button onclick="report(9876);">The third element</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      function report(val) {
        console.log(val);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
  //This will click the first button it finds
  await page.$eval('div[id^="pop_"] button', btn => btn.click());
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

[image: first result]

If you want to click ALL the buttons then your code will look like this

```
  await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
  var data = await page.$$('div[id^="pop_"] button', e => e.map((btn) => btn));
  await data[0].click();
  await data[1].click();
  await data[2].click();
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
```

Which produces the following result

[image: second result]

Answer (score -1):

You can put a `data-testid` on this button and use the `data-testid` selector instead of the long one.

[Example](https://blog.bitsrc.io/testing-your-react-app-with-puppeteer-and-jest-c72b3dfcde59)

Comment: it's not my site

Comment: It's almost as if they don't want to be crawled isn't it

Comment: You can try to select a parent element of the button that don't change and after that select the button ?

Comment: sorry I didnt get you